# Ramp up/down missing time-series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

I have a set of time-series data (GPS speed data, specifically), which includes gaps of missing values where the signal was lost. For missing periods of short durations I am about to fill simply using a na.spline, however this is inappropriate with longer time periods. I would like to ramp the values from the last true value down to zero, based on predefined acceleration limits.

```
#create sample data frame
test <- as.data.frame(c(6,5.7,5.4,5.14,4.89,4.64,4.41,4.19,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,5,5.1,5.3,5.4,5.5))
names(test)[1] <- "speed"

#set rate of acceleration for ramp
ramp <- 6

#set sampling rate of receiver
Hz <- 1/10
```

So for missing data the ramp would use the previous value and the rate of acceleration to get the next data point, until speed reached zero (i.e. last speed [4.19] + (Hz * ramp)), yielding the following values:

```
3.59
2.99
2.39
1.79
1.19
0.59
0
```

Lastly, I need to do this in the reverse fashion, to ramp up from zero when the signal picks back up again.

Hope this is clear.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's not really elegant, but you can do it in a loop.

```
na.pos <- which(is.na(test$speed))

acc = FALSE
for (i in na.pos) {
    if (acc) {
        speed <- test$speed[i-1]+(Hz*ramp)
    }
    else {
        speed <- test$speed[i-1]-(Hz*ramp)
        if (round(speed,1) < 0) {
            acc <- TRUE
            speed <- test$speed[i-1]+(Hz*ramp)
        }

    }
    test[i,] <- speed
}
```

The result is:

```
   speed
1   6.00
2   5.70
3   5.40
4   5.14
5   4.89
6   4.64
7   4.41
8   4.19
9   3.59
10  2.99
11  2.39
12  1.79
13  1.19
14  0.59
15 -0.01
16  0.59
17  1.19
18  1.79
19  2.39
20  2.99
21  3.59
22  4.19
23  4.79
24  5.00
25  5.10
26  5.30
27  5.40
28  5.50
```

Note that '-0.01', because 0.59-(6*10) is -0.01, not 0. You can round it later, I decided not to.

Answer (score 0):

When the question says "ramp the values from the last true value down to zero" in each run of NAs I assume that that means that any remaining NAs in the run after reaching zero are also to be replaced by zero.

Now, use `rleid` from data.table to create a grouping vector the same length as `test$speed` identifying each run in `is.na(test$speed)` and use `ave` to create sequence numbers within such groups, `seqno`.  Then calculate the declining sequences, `ramp_down` by combining `na.locf(test$speed)` and `seqno`.  Finally replace the NAs.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

test_speed <- test$speed
seqno <- ave(test_speed, rleid(is.na(test_speed)), FUN = seq_along)
ramp_down <- pmax(na.locf(test_speed) - seqno * ramp * Hz, 0)
result <- ifelse(is.na(test_speed), ramp_down, test_speed)
```

giving:

```
> result     
 [1] 6.00 5.70 5.40 5.14 4.89 4.64 4.41 4.19 3.59 2.99 2.39 1.79 1.19 0.59 0.00
[16] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 5.00 5.10 5.30 5.40 5.50
```

Comment: Thanks for that, worked great! Yes, I needed any following NAs to be changed to zero also, so that was fine. Now I just need to be able to run this section in the reverse order, so that when the signal picks back up there isn't a sharp jump from zero to whatever the speed when the signal picks up. Is there a way to simply run this in reverse?

Comment: In the code above set `test_speed <- rev(test$speed)` (instead of `test_speed <- test$speed`) and then the result is `rev(result)` .